# How can I process multiple dataframes and save the output in separate files using R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several data frames in R that need to be processed the same way. The output needs to be printed to separate files. This works in principle, but I have not been able to automatically assign each data frame's name as the corresponding file name.

I have tried different approaches, but I have gotten farthest by combining the data frames into a list, like so:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(pheatmap)

# Make data frames and combine in list
df1 <- data.frame("Aa" = sample(LETTERS, 5), "Bb" = 1:5, "Cc" = 3:7)
df2 <- data.frame("Aa" = sample(LETTERS, 10), "Dd" = 8:17, "Ee" = 12:21)
dflist <- list(df1, df2)

# Assign names back to data frames in list
names(dflist) <- c("df1", "df2")

# Create heatmap with each data frame and save as separate pdf file:
lapply(dflist, function(x){
  x_dflist_heatmap <- column_to_rownames(x, var = "Aa")
  pdf(paste0("heatmap_", x, ".pdf"))
  pheatmap(x_dflist_heatmap, scale = "row", main = paste0(x))
  dev.off()
})
```

This yields two pdf files with the correct heatmaps - and the very helpful names heatmap_c(2, 5, 1, 4, 3).pdf and heatmap_c(3, 9, 6, 10, 5, 2, 7, 1, 4, 8).pdf.

I assume the problem is that I am telling R to list the actual data frame, not its name, but I don't know how to solve that. Using names(x) is interpreted as using the column names of each data frame.
Bonus question: this is less critical, but if someone could let me know how I can add the newly generated data frames corresponding to "x_dflist_heatmap" to my R Data environment, that would be really cool.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: When you `lapply` over `dflist` your `x` values are the actual data.frames, not their names. `lapply` does not allow you to iterate over both names and values at same time. The `purrr::imap` function can help if you need both, otherwise try iterative over just the names and extracting the values with `dflist[[x]]` when you need the value.

Comment: I would also suggest that if you want to keep the intermediate data frames in `x_dflist_heatmap`, I would do this operation in two steps: first iterate over the original list (or it's names) and create a list with the `x_dflist_heatmap` objects; then iterate over those to create the pdfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you both for the input! I think this is more or less what you proposed, and it works perfectly:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(pheatmap)

# Make data frames and combine in list
df1 <- data.frame("Aa" = sample(LETTERS, 5), "Bb" = 1:5, "Cc" = 3:7)
df2 <- data.frame("Aa" = sample(LETTERS, 10), "Dd" = 8:17, "Ee" = 12:21)
dflist <- list(df1, df2)

# Assign names back to data frames in list
names(dflist) <- c("df1", "df2")

# Create vector with the names of the data frames in dflist
dflist_names <- names(dflist)

# Modify the list of data frames for use with pheatmap and save as a new list
dflist_heatmap <- lapply(dflist, function(x){
  x <- column_to_rownames(x, var = "Aa")
})

# Create separate pdf file for each data frame, using dflist_heatmap to generate the heatmap and dflist_names to name it
for(i in 1:length(dflist_names)){
  pdf(paste0("heatmap_", dflist_names[[i]], ".pdf"))
  pheatmap(dflist_heatmap[[i]], scale = "row", main = dflist_names[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Can you show this for complexheatmap ..I want to know how to use the column annotation

Comment: @PesKchan, I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you just want to generate a vector containing the column names of a data frame, you'd use the `colnames()` command. For instance, in the example above, `colnames(df1)` would yield a vector containing `"Aa" "Bb" "Cc"`. If your question is more complex, it might be worth a new post?

Comment: I figured it out but I will definitely ask if i have some issue with building function the way you had done here